# NDK builder r15 finds neither HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC nor pthread_condattr_setclock for some build targets; Build fails

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some native code in my project. I use pthread with monotonic time. But I'm not good in NDK development.

C code to initialise and use condition with monotonic clock:

```
int initMonotonicCond(pthread_cond_t *cond) {
    int result = 0;
#ifdef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC
    result = pthread_cond_init(cond, NULL);
#else
    pthread_condattr_t cond1attr;
    result |= pthread_condattr_init(&cond1attr);
    result |= pthread_condattr_setclock(&cond1attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    result |= pthread_cond_init(cond, &cond1attr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&cond1attr);
#endif
    return result;
}

void monothonicWait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex, const struct timespec *ts) {
#ifdef HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC
    pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np(cond, mutex, ts);
#else
    pthread_cond_timedwait(cond, mutex, ts);
#endif
}
```

Gradle builds ndk project with

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti -fPIE -fPIC"
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64"
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti -fPIE -funwind-tables -DDEBUG -fPIC"
                    abiFilters "armeabi"
                }
            }
        }
    }
.....
}
```

Recently I've updated Android Studio and all the SDK stuff to newer version. And ndk build to r15, I guess.
And now I'm getting and error when building:

Error:(155, 15) error: use of undeclared identifier 'pthread_condattr_setclock'; did you mean 'pthread_condattr_setpshared'?

After some research I've fount that now `HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC` (and `pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np`)  should be defined for non-x64 targets ("armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "x86", "mips"). And it was defined. But it is not defined now.

So, "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips" do not have defined nither `HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC` nor `pthread_condattr_setclock` defined, so my project can't be built for theese targets.

So, what's the reason for that and what options do I have?

Should I not use monothonic wait for that targets some way?

Should I not build for those targets?

Should I revert to older NDK?

Or should I write to google groups about that?

Comment: "Or should I write to google groups about that?" Filing bugs is always the best way to contact us: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_condattr_setclock` was added in android-21: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/libc.map.txt#780, so that's why you can't access it on older releases.

`HAVE_PTHREAD_COND_TIMEDWAIT_MONOTONIC` was apparently defined in the old headers. It really shouldn't have been (not with that name, anyway). Names like that are the convention used by autoconf generated things, and we shouldn't be overlapping because that can cause amcro redefinition warnings. The better way to write this check is:

```
#if defined(__ANDROID_API__) && __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
```

That's still not quite enough to get you building again though, since the declaration for `pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np` disappeared from the headers when the actual POSIX APIs for this got added. I've just uploaded a change to get the declaration re-added for the sake of compatibility: https://android-review.googlesource.com/420945

Unfortunately it's too late for this to make it into r15b. What you could do in the meantime is add your own declaration for that function:

```
extern "C" int pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np(
    pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*, const struct timespec*);
```

Comment: FYI, we're shipping an r15c to cover this and some other issues. Should be live in the next day.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the problem appeared again in 16.0.4293906 rc1.

Comment: File a bug then.